# jquery draggable list position save to database

Tags: php, jquery, sql, database

i have following code for get data from database and sort draggable list using jquery ui elements.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; background-color:#CCC;}
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
</script>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");

echo "<ul id='sortable'>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<li class='ui-state-default'>" . $row['Name'] . ' ' . $row['UserName'] . $row['sort'] ."</li>";
  }

echo "</ul>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

This is my database table structure

```
Table Name = users
Columns = user_id, Name, UserName, Password, sort
```

**Example Results**

```
user_id     Name    UserName   Password   sort
1           AAA     aa         ***        1
2           BBB     bb         ***        2
3           CCC     cc         ***        3
4           DDD     dd         ***        4
```

what i am asking is, i can Reorder list items by using jquery `draggable` properties, but how can i save `sort` number to database if reordered list items.?

Comment: Send the data via ajax using this event handler http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop

Comment: DB password `q8scool_exam` Is this a homework question?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI sortable has a stop callback which is called when you stop moving a sortable. It also has a serialize function that you can use in combination to send the order of your sortables to your to the process which updates your database. You can use it like this:

To use `serialize` you need to amend your sortable element in the DOM so that it contains a reference to the `user_id`. E.g.

```
<li class="ui-state-default" id="id_<?php echo $row['user_id'] ?>">...</li>
```

Then when you serialize the sortable, it will build a list of parameters. You don't have to use the id attribute to reference your data, read more about the [serialize method here](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize). But below is an example of how you can do it using the id attribute

```
var $sortable = $( "#sortable" );

$sortable.sortable({
    stop: function ( event, ui ) {
        // parameters will be a string "id[]=1&id[]=3&id[]=10"...etc
        var parameters = $sortable.sortable( "serialize" );

        // send new sort data to process
        $.post("/sort/my/data.php?"+parameters);
    }
});
```

You then need a process that receives this data and updates the database. I'll leave most of this up to you, but here's a minimal example.

```
<?php
// Store user IDs in array. E.g. array(0 => "1", 1 => "3", 2 => "10"....)
$userIds = $_POST['id'];

// Connect to your database
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");

foreach ($userIds as $key => $userId) {
    $sequence = $key + 1;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET sort = $sequence WHERE user_id = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", (int) $userId);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I realize this answer is a bit old, but just a heads up to anyone new coming along. Do not use `mysqli_connect`